# How to plot a horizon line equals last value of ema(2)

Tags: pine-script

I have a trading strategy, which compares ema(2) value vs ema(21)(which happens to be the middle line of bollinger band.)

So I am trying to plot a shot horizontal line which equals to the last value of ema(2), and shift it 2 - 3 time units from current bar. below is the code I am trying:

```
plot(ema(close,2)[0], title="EMA2", linewidth=2, color=color.aqua, show_last=3, offset=2)
```

However I think what I get is the last 3 time units curve and shift to the right for 2 time units.

Shouldn't the ema(close,2)[0] give me one single value equals to the last value of this ema price curve?

Comment: Please provide more information and if possible an image

Comment: Here is what I am trying to do, let's use some numbers for a simple example: today's close price is 12, yesterday close price is 8, and the simple average of the two will be 10. I am trying to plot a horizontal line at price = 10. However when I try to plot this simple average, instead of get a horizontal line at price 10, I get a curve, a price curve of simple moving average of two time units. How do I not to display this curve, but only a single last number?

Comment: I think at least I have some clue why my code doesn't work, I thought ema(close,2)[0] points to a specific data point, but it's still a time series data. so my question can be rephrased as the following: how can I specifically retrieve only yesterday's close price, a single data point, and put them into a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, you need to use the `line.new()` function

```
//@version=4
study("Help (hline)", overlay=true)

ema2 = ema(close,2)

line ln = na
line.delete(ln[1])
//ln := line.new(bar_index - 3, ema2, bar_index, ema2, width=2, color=color.aqua, extend=extend.right) 

//For intraday timeframes, three bars back and three bars forward
ln := line.new(time - timeframe.multiplier * 3 * 60 * 1000, ema2, time + timeframe.multiplier * 3 * 60 * 1000, ema2, xloc=xloc.bar_time, width=2, color=color.aqua)

//plot(ema(close,2)[0], title="EMA2", linewidth=2, color=color.aqua, show_last=3, offset=2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @AnyDozer. The script you provided worked on its own. I have a separate issue, not sure if I should open a new topic.
When I add these code to my existing script, which consists of a few other plots, including the Bollinger Bands code I copied from the system built in function. Then I will receive the following error:
"The 'resolution' argument is incompatible with functions that have side effects."
It seems it's caused by the parameter inside the study, which has resolution = "", if I delete this parameter, everything works. Do you know why?

Comment: One more thing, the code use the extend=extend.right parameter, which extends the line indefinitely to the right. I actually only want to plot it to be 3 bars or 4 bars wide, to make it look like a small indicator. Is there any way to achieve that goal?

Comment: Delete the parameter `extend=extend.right` and you will get the segment output.

Comment: I can't answer the first question without a full script. Ask a new question and publish your script.

Comment: Yes I deleted the extend = extend.right parameter, but I also want to offset the segment to the right, to make it more apparent. But line.new function doesn't support the offset parameter such as we use in Plot function.

Comment: Thanks again @AnyDozer. The new code works. And I will need to do some research and get familiar with this new time function.